# How to access a variable in my HTML file from my TS file?

Tags: angular, typescript

This is my html and ts file. I want to display a picture depending on a condition, but I cannot access my TS variable from HTML file

```js
export class ThankyouPage implements OnInit {

  dataRec: number;
    
  constructor(private activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute) {
    
  }
    ngOnInit() {

    dataRec:number;

    let dataRec= this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('high');
    console.log(dataRec);
    if (dataRec > 37.5){
      console.log('high')
    }else {
      console.log('low')
    }
   }

}
```

```html
<img *ngIf="dataRec ==38" src="../../assets/images/login.png"  />
<img *ngIf="dataRec== 40" src="../../assets/images/tfrlogo.png" />
```

Comment: Note that you likely want `dataRec` to be a `number` and then the comparison in Typescript `> '37.5'` as a `string` does not make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are wrong in `let dataRec = ...` .
If you want to set data, you have to write like this.
`this.dataRec = ...`

```
export class ThankyouPage implements OnInit {

  dataRec: number;

  constructor(private activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute) {

  }
    ngOnInit() {

    this.dataRec= this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('high');
    console.log(dataRec);
    if (dataRec > 37.5){
      console.log('high')
    }else {
      console.log('low')
    }
   }

}
<img *ngIf="dataRec ==38" src="../../assets/images/login.png"  />
<img *ngIf="dataRec== 40" src="../../assets/images/tfrlogo.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to access it from the HTML template, you need to have `dataRec` as a member of the Typescript class like:

```
class MyComponent {
  dataRec: number;
  // Assign a value to dataRec in ngOnInit for instance...
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It says "'number' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here."

Comment: Show us your code, you likely made a typo

Comment: I've just updated the code in the question.

Comment: I'd recommend that you read the basics of Typescript and Angular. The `dataRec` must be declared _outside_ the knit method.

Comment: Define "not worked", from the last code you posted , you still have a local variable `let dataRec`, you should only use the class member `this.dataRec`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a global variable and a local variable that are of the same name and type (i.e. `dataRec`)?

In `<img *ngIf="dataRec ==38" src="../../assets/images/login.png"  />`, it will try to read the global variable.

However `let dataRec= this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('high');` will set the value at the local level.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
 ngOnInit() {

    dataRec:number;

    let dataRec= this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('high'); //This is a new, local variable (bad)
    console.log(dataRec);
    if (dataRec > 37.5){
      console.log('high')
    }else {
      console.log('low')
    }
   }
```

To this:

```
 ngOnInit() {
   this.dataRec = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('high'); //this is the compoenent variable (good)
    console.log(this.dataRec);
    if (this.dataRec > 37.5){
      console.log('high')
    }else {
      console.log('low')
    }
   }
```

**Why:**

Your HTML can only access variables that are properties of your component, so anything declared on a component level is fine, but variables local to a functions aren't.
Your component variable is `dataRec: number` you declared at the top of your file.

In your case you created a variable local to `ngOnInit()` that just happened to have the same name as your component variable `dataRec`.
Instead, you need to reference the component variable, which can be done using `this.`, followed by the variable/function in your component.

In angular components, `this` refers to the component itself

Comment: Thank you! this works perfectly and the explanation makes sense. I finally understand!

Comment: You're welcome, feel free to mark my, or someone else's answer as confirmed so people don't keep answering it :)